# how to save an xlsx file with two sheets?

Tags: excel, flutter, xlsx

I want to save an xlsx file that includes two sheets in Flutter.

I searched a lot but I didn't get anything

I found that I can make one file with one sheet, which is good...but I want to do an xlsx file with two sheets.

this is the function :

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_xlsio/xlsio.dart'as xcel;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' show AnchorElement;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'dart:convert';
```

```
 Future<void> createExcel() async {
    final xcel.Workbook workbook = xcel.Workbook();
final xcel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
final xcel.Worksheet sheet2 = workbook.worksheets[00];


sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 1).setText("Title");
sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 3).setText("Link");
sheet2.getRangeByIndex(1, 2).setText("hello");


    final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
    workbook.dispose();

    if (kIsWeb) {
      AnchorElement(
          href:
              'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}')
        ..setAttribute('download', 'ok.xlsx')
        ..click();
    } else {
      final String path = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
      final String fileName =
          Platform.isWindows ? '$path\\ok.xlsx' : '$path/ok.xlsx';
      final File file = File(fileName);
      await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
      OpenFile.open(fileName);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an Excel file with two sheets in Flutter using the syncfusion_flutter_xlsio package, you can follow these steps:

1.

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_xlsio/xlsio.dart' as xcel;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' show AnchorElement;
```

2. Define a function to create the Excel file:

> Future createExcel() async {   final xcel.Workbook workbook =
> xcel.Workbook();
>
> // Create the first sheet
>
> final xcel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
> sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 1).setText("Title");
> sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 3).setText("Link");
>
> // Create the second sheet
>
> final xcel.Worksheet sheet2 =
> workbook.worksheets.addWithName("Sheet2");   sheet2.getRangeByIndex(1,
> 2).setText("hello");
>
> // Save the workbook as a stream of bytes
>
> final List bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
> workbook.dispose();
>
> if (kIsWeb) {
>
> ```
> // For web, create a download link and click it
>
> AnchorElement(
>     href:
>         'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}')
>   ..setAttribute('download', 'ok.xlsx')
>   ..click();   } else {
>
>   // For non-web platforms, save the file locally and open it
>
>   final String path = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
>   final String fileName =
>       Platform.isWindows ? '$path\\ok.xlsx' : '$path/ok.xlsx';
>   final File file = File(fileName);
>   await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
>   OpenFile.open(fileName);
> }   } }
> ```

3. Call the createExcel function when you want to create the Excel file. For example, you can trigger it with a button press.
   This code will create an Excel file with two sheets: the first sheet will have a "Title" and "Link" column, and the second sheet will have a "hello" value in cell B1. The file will be saved locally and opened for non-web platforms, while for web, a download link will be generated to download the file.